# Задержка выполнения отдельной части кода PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет, помогите решить задачу..

Как можно сделать задержку в пару секунд перед получением или показом ответа бота?
Как бы имитация того что бот набирает сообщение.

Краткая работа скрипта:

Это чат с ботом, задаешь вопрос получаешь ответ.

```
<?php 
include ('data.php'); // Подключаем массив
include ('config.php'); // Подключение к БД
$name = $_POST["text"];
$respond = $data["$name"];

//Заносим смс в БД
if (isset($_POST['text'])){
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (text,textbot) VALUES 
('$name','$respond')");
}

// Проверяем сообщения с массивом
if(!empty($data[$name])) { 
$respond;
}


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `text`, `textbot` FROM `messages` ORDER BY 
id DESC LIMIT 10", $db); // Вытаскиваем смс из таблицы

?>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="chat">
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Сообщение" 
class="message">
<button  type="submit" class="submit">Send</button></div>
</form>
<div class="chat">
<?php 
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo "<div class='p-text-bot'>".$results['textbot']."</div><br/><br/>"; // 
Ответ бота из БД
echo "<div class='p-text'>".$results['text']."</div><br/><br/>"; // Смс 
человека из БД
} 
?>
</div><br/>

</body>
```

Comment: `имитация того что бот набирает сообщение` это вроде в `js` надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var i = 4;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    i--;
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '...';
    if (i == 0) {
        document.getElementById('example').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000)
}
</script>
</head>
<?php 
include ('data.php'); // Подключаем массив
include ('config.php'); // Подключение к БД

$name = $_POST["text"];
$respond = $data["$name"];

//Заносим смс в БД
if (isset($_POST['text'])){
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (text,textbot) VALUES 
('$name','$respond')");
}

// Проверяем сообщения с массивом
if(!empty($data[$name])) { 
$respond;
}


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `ID`, `text`, `textbot` FROM `messages` where id 
not in (select max(id) from messages) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10", $db); // 
Вытаскиваем смс из таблицы
$sqlall = mysql_query("SELECT  `ID`, `text`, `textbot` FROM `messages` ORDER 
BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $db); // Вытаскиваем смс из таблицы

?>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
 <div class="chat">
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Сообщение" 
 class="message">
 <button  type="submit" class="submit">Send</button></div>
</form> 
<div class="chat">  
  <?php
  while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($sqlall)) {
    echo "<div id='timer' style='float: right;'></div> ";
    echo "<div id='example' style='display: none;' class='p-text- 
  bot'>".$results['textbot']."</div><br/><br/>"; // Ответ бота из БД
    echo "<div class='p-text'>".$results['text']."</div><br/><br/>"; // Смс 
   человека из БД
   }

   while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<div class='p-text-bot'>".$results['textbot']."</div><br/><br/>"; 
   // Ответ бота из БД
    echo "<div class='p-text'>".$results['text']."</div><br/><br/>"; // Смс 
   человека из БД
   }
  ?>
  </div><br/>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Набросал примитивный вариант. Скрываем последнее сообщение и через время показываем.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("bot");
    var last = div[div.length - 1];
    var text = last.innerHTML;
    last.innerHTML = '...';

    setTimeout(function () {
        last.innerHTML = text;
    }, 3000);
};
</script>
```

[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/zyqgbk2a/)

Comment: Я пробовал, так как вы предложили, у меня встал вопрос, как засунуть туда этот  код: 
     while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     echo "<div class='p-text-bot'>".$results['textbot']."</div><br/><br/>"; // 
     Ответ бота из БД
     echo "<div class='p-text'>".$results['text']."</div><br/><br/>"; // Смс 
     человека из БД
     }
без этого цикла программа не работает.

Comment: Это уже другая история. Учитесь искать информацию. В поиске "как вставить javascript". Добавьте JS код после вывода как обычный HTML

Answer (score -1):

Читай документацию, функция [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php)